# Swapping 1st and 2nd character of a string

Tags: assembly, x86, swap, masm, irvine32

I want to swap 2 character and 1st character. My code is:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
array byte "scs212",0

.code
main proc

mov esi,array 
mov al,[esi]
inc esi 
move bl,[esi]
xchg al,bl 
dec esi 
move [esi],al
inc esi
move [esi],bl

mov edx, offset array
call WriteString
exit 
main ENDP
END main
```

I'm trying like this but not working
result = css212

Comment: `move` should be `mov`

Comment: `mov esi,array` should be `mov esi, offset array`

Comment: You don't need `xchg al,bl`.  Just store `bl` instead of `al` and so on.  Actually you're already doing that, so you swapped both the registers and the memory addressing.  (Use a debugger to see registers and memory as you single-step.)

Comment: This isn't a [mcve].  Include the actual behaviour in the question as well as the desired.  "doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: _"I want to swap 2 character and 1st character. I'm trying like this but not working result = css212"_ How is that not exactly what you want..?

Comment: You can do the whole thing in one instruction: `rol word ptr [array], 8`.  (16-bit rotate by half the width swaps bytes)

Answer (score 0):

```
MOV  ESI,offset array   ;pointer to first position
MOV  AL,[ESI]
INC  ESI 
MOV  BL,[ESI]
XCHG AL,BL 
DEC  ESI 
MOV  [ESI],AL
INC  ESI
MOV  [ESI],BL
INC  ESI
```